# How to get my hdfs docker client running?

Tags: hadoop, docker, hdfs

I'm starting an [hdfs server](https://github.com/sequenceiq/hadoop-docker) with:

```
docker run -d sequenceiq/hadoop-docker:2.6.0
```

I'm observing the running docker processes with

```
docker ps
```

Which gets the following result:

```
6bfa4f2fd3b5        sequenceiq/hadoop-docker:2.6.0   "/etc/bootstrap.sh -d"   
31 minutes ago      Up 31 minutes       22/tcp, 8030-8033/tcp, 8040/tcp, 
8042/tcp, 8088/tcp, 49707/tcp, 50010/tcp, 50020/tcp, 50070/tcp, 50075/tcp, 
50090/tcp   kind_hawking
```

I'm trying to [connect via `hdfs`](https://github.com/davvdg/hdfs-client) to my docker container with:

```
sudo docker run -ti davvdg/hdfs-client hadoop fs -fs hdfs://localhost:50075 -ls /
```

This gives the following resut:

```
ls: Call From a48f81b8e1bb/172.17.0.3 to localhost:50075 failed on 
connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For 
more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

My question is: **How to get my hdfs docker client running?**

---

Edit:
Thanks to some helpful feedback from @shizhz I'm updating the question.

Here is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM sequenceiq/hadoop-docker:2.6.0

CMD ["/etc/bootstrap.sh", "-d"]

# Hdfs ports
EXPOSE 50010 50020 50070 50075 50090 8020 9000
# Mapred ports
EXPOSE 10020 19888
#Yarn ports
EXPOSE 8030 8031 8032 8033 8040 8042 8088
#Other ports
EXPOSE 49707 2122

EXPOSE 9000

EXPOSE 2022
```

Here is how I'm building the image:

```
 sudo docker build -t my-hdfs .
```

Here is how I'm running the image:

```
sudo docker run -d -p my-hdfs
```

Here is how I'm checking the processes:

```
sudo docker ps
```

with a result like:

```
d9c9855cfaf0        my-hdfs             "/etc/bootstrap.sh -d"   2 minutes ago       
Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:32801->22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32800->2022/tcp, 
0.0.0.0:32799->2122/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32798->8020/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32797->8030/tcp, 
0.0.0.0:32796->8031/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32795->8032/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32794->8033/tcp, 
0.0.0.0:32793->8040/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32792->8042/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32791->8088/tcp, 
0.0.0.0:32790->9000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32789->10020/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32788->19888/tcp, 
0.0.0.0:32787->49707/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32786->50010/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32785->50020/tcp, 
0.0.0.0:32784->50070/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32783->50075/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32782->50090/tcp   
agitated_curran
```

Here is how I'm getting the IP address:

```
docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' d9c9855cfaf0
```

with a result like:

```
172.17.0.3
```

Here is how I'm running the test:

```
sudo docker run --rm sequenceiq/hadoop-docker:2.6.0 /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/bin/hadoop fs -fs hdfs://192.168.0.3:9000 -ls /
```

With a result like:

```
17/04/08 19:51:54 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 
192.168.0.3/192.168.0.3:9000. Already tried 0 time(s); maxRetries=45
ls: Call From fafcd377f4a0/172.17.0.2 to 192.168.0.3:9000 failed on connection 
exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details 
see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

My question is: **How to get my hdfs docker client running?**

Comment: Did you opened the ports on your hdfs server container putting -p option in docker run command?

Comment: Did you mount any `hdfs-site.xml` or `core-site.xml` into the container? Otherwise, how does the client know how to access the server?

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007 that's helpful. Surely the address you pass in overrides that?

Comment: Yes, using the IP for `hadoop fs -fs hdfs://192.168.0.3:9000` will override that, but there are still other important things in those config files

Comment: Anyway, the expose on dockerfile is needed. The ports with expose are able to be mapped, but is needed also the -p on docker run to really map them to the host.

Comment: @OscarAkaElvis They get bound "at random" without `-p`. See `0.0.0.0:32790->9000/tcp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the client, you could use the thin docker image just for client like hdfs client.
one of them are pretty good that I've used before: https://hub.docker.com/r/ryneyang/hadoop-utils/

Answer (score 2):

By default, each container will use `bridge` network driver and has its own isolation network environment. It's not the same thing but you can just simply think they are different servers and has their own private IPs. So when you started a client container and try to connect the address `hdfs://localhost:50075`, it'll actually try to connect the port `50075` of itself, rather than connecting the hadoop server container, obviously it'll be refused. Please refer to their [official network docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/) for more info.

Containers on the same host can communicate with each other by their private IPs, so to connect to your hadoop server container, you can firstly find out it private IP by:

```
$> docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' 378
192.168.0.2
```

And then I can use the client by(And I think the port should be 9000):

```
$> docker run --rm sequenceiq/hadoop-docker:2.6.0 /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/bin/hadoop fs -fs hdfs://192.168.0.2:9000 -ls /
Found 1 items
drwxr-xr-x   - root supergroup          0 2015-01-15 04:04 /user
```

If you want to run client container on another host, then you need to know [multi-host networking](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-overlay/).

Comment: Thanks @shizhz - I'm not yet convinced you started the first container and then ran the second as a client. It looks like you just ran the command on the original host when it first started up. Thanks for being helpful. I'll update the question.

Comment: Glad to help @hawkeye, but why you got ip `172.17.0.3` for your server container, but use `hdfs://192.168.0.3:9000`  when you ran your client container?

Comment: I checked your Dockerfile and found it does nothing more but expose an extra port `2022`, but this port is not used in your server container, so is there reason you have to do this? And additionally, mapping ports to host with `-p` is to expose your service inside container to the outside world, and also is one of ways to do multi-host communication between containers. As I mentioned in my answer, if you just want to test `client` and `server` on the same machine, you don't have to do this to make them be capable of talking to each other, using IPs of the container is just enough.